# How to get only json value using jquery from calling an API?

Tags: python, jquery, json, flask

The API returns both JSON and also render the template and when i call `$.getJSON` it will only return that render template but not JSON value. I have tried this

```
 if request.args['type'] == 'json':
    return json.dumps(group)
 else:
    return render_template("/c.., summary=json.dumps(group))
```

but it says

> bad request

Is there any way I can get that JSON value whenever I need it?

This is my view

```
@cms.route('/add/asset/<client_id>', methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def asset_add(client_id):
    if int(current_user.id_) == int(client_id):
        group = {}
        group['id'] = []
        group['pid'] = []
        group['name'] = []
        for index in range(len([r.id_ for r in db.session.query(Assetgroup.id_)])):
            for asset in (Assetgroup.query.filter_by(parent_id=(index or ''))):
                group['id'].append(asset.id_)
                group['pid'].append(asset.parent_id)
                group['name'].append(asset.name)
        if request.args['type'] == 'json':
            return json.dumps(group)
        else:
            return render_template("/cms/asset_add.html", action="/add/asset", asset=None,
                               client_id=client_id, 
                               types=Type.query.all())
    else:
        return 'permission denied'
```

and this is my ajax request

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                                $('#group_id').click(function () {
                                    $.getJSON(
                                        '/add/asset/' + {{ client_id }},
                                        function (data) {
                                            $('#group_id').find('option').remove();
                                            var len = data.id.length;
                                            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                                                var option_item = '<option value="' + data.id[i] + '">' + data.name[i] + "</option>";
                                                $('#group_id').append(option_item);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    );
                                });
                            });
```

Comment: Some more information would be helpful.

Comment: The entire flask view. The AJAX call, the input data, desired output.

Comment: @pissall Do you want your view function to return html and json both? I think your view return is fine. Are you sure you passing the correct get parameter to your view ? like this `localhost:5000/test?type=json`

Comment: @RajaSimon I want to see the entire view. And the AJAX call to see if it is receiving correctly.

Comment: Well passing `type` in get request and still if you're not getting the json then I may be misunderstood your question. Can you please atleast show the ajax call and the entire view asked by @pissall

Comment: @RishavManiBhurtel Is it worked ?

Comment: Well you're not passing `type` in the url parameter so it will return only html template.

Comment: I made the answer. Let's continue discuss over there. Please delete these comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169228/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-pissall).

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameter in html call to get the json result...

i.e)

```
const Endpoint = '/add/asset/?'

$.getJSON(Endpoint, {type: 'json'}).done(function(data...)
```

Comment: it still says Bad Request.

Comment: Okay now can you check the terminal and see you get the type=json in GET method ?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Apr/2018 14:57:34] "GET /add/asset/1 HTTP/1.1" 400 -

Comment: Okay I see the `client_id` which is good. Now please put `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` after the opening of `if` statement and then run the server. This will enable debug mod and press `n` for next let's see where the error occours. It's just for debugging.

Comment: may be i will just make another view and return json from it. it will be very simple and easy.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.is_json

That is a flask method that checks if the request is json

Then you can use jsonify still in flask to return json (you need to import it though)

```
from flask import  jsonify
```

so your code becomes

```
if request.is_json:
     return jsonify(group)
```

Hope you find that useful and more elegant

One of the easier ways to debug is just return json alone for a start to see how the response looks in a browser. So you can remove login required (assuming you are not yet in production), do not check if the request is_json, then call the api and see what it returns. So assuming your client id is 1

```
@cms.route('/add/asset/<client_id>', methods=["GET"])
def asset_add(client_id):
    if int(current_user.id_) == int(client_id):
        group = {}
        group['id'] = []
        group['pid'] = []
        group['name'] = []
        for index in range(len([r.id_ for r in db.session.query(Assetgroup.id_)])):
            for asset in (Assetgroup.query.filter_by(parent_id=(index or ''))):
                group['id'].append(asset.id_)
                group['pid'].append(asset.parent_id)
                group['name'].append(asset.name)

        return jsonify(group)
```

Now you can visit http://yoursite.com/add/asset/1 to see your response